# How can we validate an ePub3 file in Windows 8 system

Tags: epubcheck

We have validate an ePub files in the epubcheck-3.0.1 version in windows 8.1 system, and we received below error message in the epub files. could you please help for us?

ERROR: 9088098774672.epub: Mimetype entry missing or not the first in archive
Validating against EPUB version 3.0

Check finished with warnings or errors

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to Windows itself. This means that ePub file is bad compressed. Decompress this file and compress it via this tool [ePubPack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/epubpack/)

Comment: We have properly compressed in the ePub file in windows 8 machine. but we received the same error in the epubchecker 3.0.1. Can you please try in windows 8 machine and let me know the solution?

Comment: I check it an minute ago and it is working.